# 1000 Days after Birth

Tags: c#, datetime

I recently joined a course about C# and I'm really enjoying it but I've got an exercise in which I have to write a date and it should give me back a date after 1000 days. I write some kind of code after a research about the DateTime type but it always gives me a date after 1001 days and not 1000 days. Also I don't want to have time on my final result so I really need help.... I want to apologies if my topic is dumb af... I just made an account here and that's my first post.
So here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace _1000DaysAfterBirthV2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string birthDate = Console.ReadLine();
            DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(birthDate).Date;
            DateTime.ParseExact(birthDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
            DateTime birthday = DateTime.Parse(birthDate);
            DateTime after = birthday.AddDays(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(after);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DateTime after = birthday.AddDays(999);` ?

Comment: Yep, it worked I wasn't really sure about that tbh and what about removing the time from the end result

Comment: Which date do you expect as 1 day after birth? The next day or the same day? If you expect it to be the next day, then your current ouput is correct

Comment: There is a difference in "The thousands day after birth" => dob.AddDays(999) and "thousand days have passed from birth" => dob.AddDays( 1000 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for showing the date without the time, look into the [.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
after.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
```

It is similar to your parsing,  MM for month vs mm for minutes.  The different representative parts.  Pick whatever parts you want in your output.  Similar applications of ToString() are used for numeric fields too, such as int, decimal, float to show leading/trailing zeros, decimal precision, etc.  All objects have a default "ToString()" method which you can even define your own on your own custom classes when you get that far down...

CLARIFICATION

Calling it is exactly as I have it above based on your reference to the "after" DateTime variable type.  ToString() returns a string with a specific format.
When you are calling WriteLine(), that is expecting a string.  Since you are passing in your "after" DateTime, the method knows it needs to call the respective .ToString() and implies a default output.  All the above sample does is explicitly tells WriteLine to print the date field "after", but using the SPECIFIC format included.  If you wanted the date shown in other formats you could do

```
after.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") -- year first, then month and day.
after.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") -- day first, then month, then year
after.ToString("MM-yyyy" )   -- to only show 2-digit month and 4-digit year
```

Comment: Can you show me any example of how exactly ToString() should be used

Comment: @Stormcho, see revised answer for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

What we call the fifth day after a particular event has a date four days later. Friday of next week is the fifth day after Monday, so

```
  DateTime friday = monday.AddDays(4);
```

The same goes for the thousandth day after an event.

```
  DateTime after = birthday.AddDays(999);
```

Comment: Okay, thanks it worked and what about removing the time from the end result

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateString = Console.ReadLine();
        string format= "dd-MM-yyyy";
        DateTime result=DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, 

CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTime output = Convert.ToDateTime(result).AddDays(999);
        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

I think that would do. :)