# 1000 Days after Birth in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-formatting

I'm struggling to complete the following exercise:
I have to declare a function that should read the **birthdate** in **"dd-MM-yyyy"** format, then **add 1000 days** to it **and then return the new date in the same format**. Input: **1995-02-25** / Output: **20-11-1997**. Hints are given: use setDate(), getDate(), getMonth() and getFullYear(). There is a tool that evaluates the code in five tests. **Note** according to the tool 21-11-1997 should be the returned value. Normally I should add 999 to seDate().

---

1) Here I passed the first of five test as I returned the correct output. But I guess the input could not be placed there.

```js
function addDays() {

    function formatDate(date) {
        let dd = date.getDate();
        let MM = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let yyyy = date.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd;
        }
        if (MM < 10) {
            MM = '0' + MM;
        }
        return dd + '-' + MM + '-' + yyyy;
    }

    let birthday = new Date('1995-02-25');

    let birthDate = formatDate(birthday);
    return formatDate(new Date(birthday.setDate(birthday.getDate() + 1000)));
}
console.log(addDays()); // 21-11-1997
```

---

2) Here the output is NaN, so the first test is failed, but the forth test is passed. I think due to the fact that I put an argument in the addDays() function that is passed on the variables. But I'm not sure.

```js
function addDays(x) {

    function formatDate(date) {
        let dd = date.getDate();
        let MM = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let yyyy = date.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd;
        }
        if (MM < 10) {
            MM = '0' + MM;
        }
        return dd + '-' + MM + '-' + yyyy;
    }

    let y = new Date(x);
    let birthday = formatDate(y);

    return formatDate(new Date(y.setDate(y.getDate() + 1000)))
}

console.log(addDays("1995-02-25"));
```

---

I'm new to JS and programming as a whole. Actually I'm learning JS since two weeks and I've spent half of the time dealing whit this. I would be very grateful if you guys can help me with that. I guess that I've missed something in the algorithm as well in other parts.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify: _nd then return the new date in the same format. Input: 1995-02-25 / Output: 20-11-1997._ These dates are not in the **same** format.

Comment: `birthdate in "dd-MM-yyyy"` as input format, but you're inputing `1995-02-25` which is `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: Hint: try to convert the date to milliseconds, and then back to a date. You can just calculate how many milliseconds 1000 days are to add them.

Comment: @lux don't need to do that. setDate will handle the conversion.

Comment: @RandyCasburn and Geuis. Yes, the input is yyyy-MM-dd, but the the function should read it as "dd-MM-yyyy". Also "dd-MM-yyyy" is invalid input. Therefore I use the formatDate(date); to convert it.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Please clarify: `Yes, the input is yyyy-MM-dd, but the the function should read it as "dd-MM-yyyy".`

Comment: @Geuis as far as I know it goes like this. See in the second code. The input, when invoked goes to the arg in `function addDays(x)`, and from there to `let y = new Date(x);` where it is a full text string. from there I use the `formatDate(date)` function to convert the date to `dd-MM-yyyy` format. From now on the birthday is in this format and I think that solves the first part of the assignment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42747220/1000-days-after-birth?answertab=active#tab-top I'm pretty sure that this guy has this exercise from the same place but for C#. Can be useful.

Comment: One issue is that `new Date('1995-02-25')` will parse the string as UTC, but you're formatting the date using local, so it may appear to be one day out depending on the user's timezone. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with the code, both bits work fine.

Comment: @RobG Yep, they work and i have some more working codes, one HTML even, but the checking system does not give me the full score. I guess I'm missing a condition in the assignment. Do you thing that `getUTCDate()` etc. would be better?